# vb.net custom datatable class

Tags: vb.net, class, datatable

I would like to create a custom *datatable* class in which the *datarow* class
property **"Item"** is overloaded so that it returns a trimmed value.

How do I start? Maybe an example?

```
Class MyDatatable
Inherits DataTable

Public Overloads Property Item(ByVal columnIndex As Integer) As Object
Get

End Get
Set(value As Object)

End Set
End Property

End Class
```

Thx!

Comment: Create a new class that inherits `DataTable` and contains an `Item` property.

Comment: This is what I have so far... (not much!) See Q

Comment: I don't know enought about DataTable to help you directly. But maybe you'll have to loop all items and trim them, or have the database query return a trimmed version of the string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't much to overload since the DataTable doesn't have an `Item` property.  What you really want to do is inherit from DataRow, but that doesn't work because it has a required initializer (`DataRowBuilder`) that is inaccessible.

Maybe something like this:

```
Public Class MyDataTable
  Inherits DataTable

  Public Function Item(ByVal rowIndex As Integer, _
                       ByVal columnIndex As Integer) As Object
    Return MyBase.Rows(rowIndex)(columnIndex).ToString().Trim
  End Function

End Class
```

It's missing some obvious error checking.  Not very practical either, since a cell could hold a lot more types than just strings.

Comment: Hi LarsTech, thanks for this.

The datatype in the cells will always be **returned** as string (IBM iSeries AS400) so not very error prone. Because the DataRowBuilder is inaccessable preventing to initialize DataRow class I think I'll have to mark your answer as definitive. =)

grtz